# How to create logic_hook in SugarCRM 7.2.*?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I need to activate and save a logic_hook file and make always validate records in Opportunities module before saving then in database.
I tried to search how can I do this but I don't know which directory and how can I execute my php file.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the best practice one could place the initiation for the logic hook in a flexible way with a unique name. The reason for this is that packages installed with Module Loader might overwrite your custom files when they are named with the default logic_hooks.php.

Example from the Sugar Developer guide:

```
./custom/Extension/modules/<module>/Ext/LogicHooks/<unique_filename>.php 

<?php

$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(
    1, 
    'Custom Logic', 
    'custom/modules/<module>/<module>_hook.php', 
    'my_hook_class', 
    'example_method'
);
```

```
./custom/modules/<module>/<unique_name><module>_hook.php

<?php

if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class my_hook_class
{
    function example_method($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```